# urls to html files generated by applications in openshift environment

Tags: html, openshift

My (java) application (in openshift environment) generates/updates a few html files for each user (based on changes of user data) on daily basis.  Since these are application-generated files, they are stored in a directory under ~/jbosseap/ (e.g. ~/jbosseap/htmls/xxxxxx.html). what should be the urls to these html files, by which they can be accessed on internet?

Comment: After exploring for an answer to the question, I think it is better phrased as follows: how to access static content (html pages) in openshift jbosseap environment? These html pages are generated by an application, NOT DEPLOYED WITH ROOT.war

Answer (score 0):

Just an update on how have I solved the problem I presented above. First of all, it is good to rephrase the issue for clarity:

**My objective**: I have an application which creates/updates a set of html pages regularly. These pages are stored (by the application) in a directory on the file system. For the purpose of this writing, let's say the fullpath to the directory is "/opt/mydata/*".

Users of the app need to access these html pages from internet. Therefore, urls to these pages need to be provided: e.g., http://mycompany.com/static/sample.html for /opt/mydata/sample.html.

**My environment**: my app is a J2EE application, developed with Springframework 3.1, running in Openshift's jbosseap environment

**My solution**: add the following line to the (servlet's) context configuration:

`<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="file:/opt/mydata/"/>`

The trick, I think, is "**file:**" in the clause to allow inclusion of resources 
on a file system external to the application.

It has worked for me. Hope it helps anyone who have wondered too.

**Credit** Thanks to Eugen Paraschiv, whose [post](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources) led me to the answer.